# SQL syntax question for creating a calculated column

Tags: sql, ms-access, calculated-columns

I thought below would work:

```
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN weighted_score AS (IS NOT NULL(score='H')*2 + IS NOT NULL(score='L')*1 )
```

but I get

> "Syntax error in field definition" 3292

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that ou are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: You are adding a **column**.  You cannot assign any values to individual rows until table modification has been completed.

Comment: Depending on the database you use you might be able to setup a default value for a **new** row.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can't figure out what that code attempt is supposed to do.

Comment: I don't think ALTER TABLE can handle creating a Calculated type field. Might be able to with TableDefs. Why would you need code to modify table design? Do this table edit manually or better, do calculation in SELECT query.